# Google AdWords Java API: Help unmarshal Ad Hoc Report

Tags: java, google-ads-api

I'm using [google-api-adwords-java](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-java/) to download some [Ad Hoc](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/guides/reporting.html) AdWords reports.

The library helps me to build the request xml through usage of:

```
com.google.api.adwords.lib.utils.v201109.ReportUtils.toXml(reportDefinition)
```

I am successfully able to obtain the response xml, but I see no way through the API to map that to java objects. Is there anything within the API to help me do so or is this something I am going to have to do on my own?

(I am currently using adwords-api-8.4.2)

Comment: change the link, it has moved to https://github.com/googleads/googleads-java-lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to parse the xml on your own, since report downloads don't have corresponding POJO objects in AdWords API. Though, it should be easy to do using some basic XML parsing code. All the reports (when downloaded in xml format) looks like this:

```
<report>
  <report-name name="Report name here"/>
    <date-range date="date-range-here"/>
      <table>
        <columns>
          <column name="columnName" display="Display name of column"/>
          ....
        </columns>
        <row columnName="value" columnName="value" .../>
        ....
  </table>
</report>
```

I also wanted to mention that our primary discussion forum is at http://groups.google.com/group/adwords-api?pli=1, and I frequently answer developer questions there, so if you have any followup questions, feel free to ask there and I'll be happy to answer your questions.

Cheers,
Anash

Comment: I has another question and directed it towards your discussion forum. I didn't get much of a response so I also asked on SO (interesting to see if it gets answered here first): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911617/adwords-api-v201109-ad-hoc-keyword-performance-report-display-network-performanc