# AdWords API v201109 Ad Hoc Keyword Performance Report Display Network Performance

Tags: google-ads-api

When running a Keyword report in **AdWords API v13**, the data for **both** the Search and 
Display Network will be returned in the same report.

I have tried running the **v201109 Ad Hoc Keyword Performance Report** and 
it never returns the Display Network data. I have added a predicate 
(where AdNetworkType1 is CONTENT or SEARCH), but this does not help. 
If I run the (in this case) Managed Placements Performance Report, all 
the Display data comes through as expected.

Is this the way this is supposed to work or is there some type of 
issue within the API?

If this is supposed to work this way, why is AdNetworkType1 
available in the Keyword Performance report as a predicate?

Is there any single report that can give me both the keyword breakdown and the 
Display Network stats? Will I have to run two (or more) separate reports now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The v201109 KEYWORDS report only returns data related to keyword criteria.  Other criteria types that work on the Display Network can be fetched using the generic CRITERIA report.

FYI, in the future you may also want to post your questions on the official AdWords API forum: http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/community/

Comment: For anyone who is wondering how to do this using the Criteria report, you need to include the Criteria field, which will be keyword text for keyword impressions. You will also need to heed the Ad Network if you need to distinguish as Display Network impressions will look like keyword impressions otherwise.